# I have troubles making list of list of list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Hi everyone im new on python and I have some troubles trying to organize the data .

I have these lists ***nuxdx, nuxdy, nuydx, nuydy***  that have 166 elements (which represent gradiendts for 166 geographic points) which each one of them has 1000 elements ().

```
M = []
for i in range(len(nuxdx[0])):      # len(nuxdx[0]) = 1000
    for j in range(len(nuxdx)):     # len(nuxdx) = 166
        Ma = [nuxdx[j][i],(nuxdy[j][i]+nuydx[j][i])/2, (nuydx[j][i]+nuxdy[j][i])/2, nuxdx[j][i]]
        M.append(Ma)
```

What im trying to do up there is to select the first element of the first sublist for each list. The objective is to create a list that contains 1000 elements where each element is a list with 166 elements where each element have 4 numbers. 
What i want is a list (lets call it MM) that contain 1000 **M** so:

```
len(MM) = 1000
len(MM[0]) = 166
len(MM[0][0]) = 4
```

Comment: you mean you want a list of quadrouples?
Like `new_list = [(a1,b2, c1,d1), (a2, b2, c2, d2) ...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
MM = []
for i in range(len(nuxdx[0])):      # len(nuxdx[0]) = 1000
    M = []
    for j in range(len(nuxdx)):     # len(nuxdx) = 166
        Ma = [nuxdx[j][i],(nuxdy[j][i]+nuydx[j][i])/2, (nuydx[j][i]+nuxdy[j][i])/2, nuxdx[j][i]]
        M.append(Ma)
    MM.append(M)
```

Comment: I already tried it but it didnt work, it just gave me a list MM of size 166000

Comment: Consider upvoting helpful answers @JuanPabloMerino. It's a nice gesture.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a 1000x166x4 3-D multi-array?

In the code above it looks like you'll end up with a 166000x4 2-D multi-array. Since `M = []` to start, and you're just appending a 4 element list to it for every `ij' combination. Does that make sense? To do what you want with the code above, you should just need to add another list:

```
M = []
for i in range(len(nuxdx[0])):      # len(nuxdx[0]) = 1000
    N = []                          # list of lists (2-D)
    for j in range(len(nuxdx)):     # len(nuxdx) = 166
        Ma = [nuxdx[j][i],(nuxdy[j][i]+nuydx[j][i])/2, (nuydx[j][i]+nuxdy[j][i])/2, nuxdx[j][i]]
        N.append(Ma)
    M.append(N)                     # list of lists of lists (3-D)
```

That should do it.

As an aside, you might want to look into using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) for this - which provides more efficient operations of arrays/multiarrays. [This might help?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-n-dimensional-arrays-python-numpy/)

Comment: Yes I want a 1000x166x4 3-D multi-array and I already tried the way you say but it didnt work, it just gave me a list M of size 166000

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `zip()` and also use quadruples.

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
d = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']

collect = []

for i, j, h, k in zip(a, b, c, d):
    collect.append((i, j, h, k))

print(collect)
```

> `[('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'), ('a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3')]`